# Invert Elements in ArrayList<Integer> Java

Tags: java, arraylist, integer

Ok so the point of this method is the invert the elements in an ArrayList of type `<Integer>`. So if I have the elements:

```
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

once I call the method, the position of the elements should be Inverted as such:

```
10
9
8
7
6
5
```

This is the method, any advice would be greatly appreciated :).

```
public void invertElements()
{
    for (int i = list.size()-1; i <= -1; i--)
    {
        int temp = list.get(i);
        for(int j = 0; j < list.size()-1; j++)
        {
        list.set(j, temp);
        }
        
    }
}
```

list is the name of my `ArrayList<Integer>`.

Update: Just tried this way:

```
public void invertElements()
{
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = list.size()-1; i > -1; i--)
    {
        int temp = list.get(i);
        list.set(index, temp);
        index++;
        if(index == list.size()-1)
        {
            break;
        }           
    }
}
```

which gives the output: 10, 9, 8, 9, 10
Could someone explain to me why?

Comment: Why don't use `Collections.reverse(list);` ?

Comment: @ZouZou and exercise maybe?

Comment: `(int i=list.size()-1; i <= -1; i--)` something is wrong here...

Comment: Hint: you can do it by traversing half of the list only O(N) instead of traversing the list several times O(N^2).

Comment: Yes I'm doing this purely for practice

Comment: 'i <= -1' is an obvious mistake. You have to write 'i > -1'

Comment: Do it manually on paper; make notes and then you know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can take the extremities of the list at each iteration and swap them :

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10));
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size()/2; i++){
                int temp = list.get(i);
                int temp2 = list.get(list.size()-1-i);
                list.set(i, temp2);
                list.set(list.size()-1-i, temp);
      }
        for(Integer i : list)
            System.out.print(i+"-");
```

Gives the output :

> 10-9-8-7-6-5-4-3-2-1-

At the first iteration : `temp = 1 / temp2 = 10` : we swap them
At the second iteration : `temp = 2 / temp2 = 9` : we swap them

And we loop until we go through all the elem of the list which is the size of the list divided by 2.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is

```
public void invertElems(List<Integer> list) {
  for (int i = 0; i < list.size() / 2; ++i) { // we only need iterating half of the size of list
    int elem = list.get(i); // we store element in additional variable
    list.set(i, list.get(list.size() - i - 1)); // we set i-th elementh with i-th element from the back
    list.set(list.size() - i - 1, elem);
  }
}
```

Linear time. Feel free to ask questions.